# When to use Spring Security`s antMatcher()?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security4

When do we use `antMatcher()` vs `antMatchers()`?

For example:

```java
http
   .antMatcher("/high_level_url_A/**")
   .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/high_level_url_A/sub_level_1").hasRole('USER')
      .antMatchers("/high_level_url_A/sub_level_2").hasRole('USER2')
      .somethingElse()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
   .antMatcher("/high_level_url_B/**")
   .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/high_level_url_B/sub_level_1").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/high_level_url_B/sub_level_2").hasRole('USER3')
      .somethingElse()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
   ...
```

What I expect here is,

- Any request matches to `/high_level_url_A/**` should be authenticated +  `/high_level_url_A/sub_level_1` only for USER and `/high_level_url_A/sub_level_2` only for USER2
- Any request matches to `/high_level_url_B/**` should be authenticated +  `/high_level_url_B/sub_level_1` for public access and `/high_level_url_A/sub_level_2` only for USER3.
- Any other pattern I don't care - But should be public ?

I have seen latest examples do not include `antMatcher()` these days. Why is that? Is `antMatcher()` no longer required?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You need [`antMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#antMatcher-java.lang.String-) for multiple [`HttpSecurity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html), see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity):

> **5.7 Multiple HttpSecurity**
>
> We can configure multiple HttpSecurity instances just as we can have multiple `<http>` blocks. The key is to extend the `WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` multiple times. For example, the following is an example of having a different configuration for URL’s that start with `/api/`.
>
> ```
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
>   @Autowired
>   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 1
>       auth
>           .inMemoryAuthentication()
>               .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
>               .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
>   }
>
>   @Configuration
>   @Order(1)                                                        2
>   public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>           http
>               .antMatcher("/api/**")                               3
>               .authorizeRequests()
>                   .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
>                   .and()
>               .httpBasic();
>       }
>   }    
>
>   @Configuration                                                   4
>   public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>       @Override
>       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>           http
>               .authorizeRequests()
>                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
>                   .and()
>               .formLogin();
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> 1 Configure Authentication as normal
>
> 2 Create an instance of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that contains `@Order` to specify which `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` should be considered first.
>
> 3 The `http.antMatcher` states that this `HttpSecurity` will only be applicable to URLs that start with `/api/`
>
> 4 Create another instance of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. If the URL does not start with `/api/` this configuration will be used. This configuration is considered after `ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` since it has an `@Order` value after `1` (no `@Order` defaults to last).

In your case you need no [`antMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#antMatcher-java.lang.String-), because you have only one configuration. Your modified code:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/high_level_url_A/sub_level_1").hasRole('USER')
        .antMatchers("/high_level_url_A/sub_level_2").hasRole('USER2')
        .somethingElse() // for /high_level_url_A/**
        .antMatchers("/high_level_url_A/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/high_level_url_B/sub_level_1").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/high_level_url_B/sub_level_2").hasRole('USER3')
        .somethingElse() // for /high_level_url_B/**
        .antMatchers("/high_level_url_B/**").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
```

Answer (score 71):

I'm updating my answer...

`antMatcher()` is a method of `HttpSecurity`, it doesn't have anything to do with `authorizeRequests()`.  Basically, `http.antMatcher()` tells Spring to only configure `HttpSecurity` if the path matches this pattern.

The `authorizeRequests().antMatchers()` is then used to apply authorization to one or more paths you specify in `antMatchers()`.  Such as `permitAll()` or `hasRole('USER3')`.  These only get applied if the first `http.antMatcher()` is matched.

Comment: what does "ant" in antMatcher stand for?

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere It's a reference to Apache's Ant build tool. It has a somewhat unique way of handling pattern matching, which `antMatcher` borrows from. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html