# Is @Autowired required on configureGlobal(..) when using @EnableWebSecurity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In this example there is an `@Autowired` annotation on the `configureGlobal` method:

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
      @Autowired
      public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
          auth
              .inMemoryAuthentication()
                  .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                  .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
      }
```

Is that necessary or does Spring automatically inject the AuthenticationBuilder on methods annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity?`?

The code snippet is pulled from [when-to-use-spring-securitys-antmatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890540/when-to-use-spring-securitys-antmatcher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Spring documentation `@EnableWebSecurity` is an annotation that only switches off the default web application security configuration in order to let you add some custom features like the `configureGlobal`.

`configureGlobal` should be `@Autowired` in order to get the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` bean and define the authentication type for the application.

In conclusion `@EnableWebSecurity` doesn't inject beans, it only provides a way to customize the web security application.

[`@EnableWebSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html)