# After Applying Spring Security in my project, controller not working, whenever i called the rest controllers, its simply response with 404 code

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, http-status-code-404

After Applying Spring Security in my project, controller not working, whenever I called the rest controllers, it's simply response with 404 code.

This is my Spring Security Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

My Application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.62:3306/dummy_users?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = MySQL62$$
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

My Initial Data Loader class

```
package com.dummy.users.auth.config;

import com.dummy.users.auth.entity.Privilege;
import com.dummy.users.auth.entity.UsersProfileEntity;
import com.dummy.users.auth.entity.UsersRoles;
import com.dummy.users.auth.repository.PrivilegeRepository;
import com.dummy.users.auth.repository.UserProfileRepository;
import com.dummy.users.auth.repository.UsersRolesRepository;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class InitialDataLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    boolean alreadySetup = false;

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UsersRolesRepository usersRolesRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PrivilegeRepository privilegeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        if (alreadySetup) {
            return;
        }
        Privilege readPrivilege
                = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("READ_PRIVILEGE");
        Privilege writePrivilege
                = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("WRITE_PRIVILEGE");

        List<Privilege> adminPrivileges = Arrays.asList(
                readPrivilege, writePrivilege);
        createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_ADMIN", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_USER", Arrays.asList(readPrivilege));

//        UsersRoles adminRole = usersRolesRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
//        UsersProfileEntity user = new UsersProfileEntity();
//        user.setFirstName("KarthickRaj");
//        user.setLastName("Rathinakumar");
//        user.setPhoneNumber("95245356782");
//        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("2342423$$#"));
//        user.setEmailId("rkarthickraj@gmail.com");
//        user.setStatus("Active");
//        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(adminRole));
//        user.setEnabled(true);
//        userProfileRepository.save(user);
        alreadySetup = true;
    }

    @Transactional
    private Privilege createPrivilegeIfNotFound(String name) {

        Privilege privilege = privilegeRepository.findByName(name);
        if (privilege == null) {
            privilege = new Privilege();
            privilege.setName(name);
            privilegeRepository.save(privilege);
        }
        return privilege;
    }

    @Transactional
    private UsersRoles createRoleIfNotFound(
            String name, Collection<Privilege> privileges) {

        UsersRoles role = usersRolesRepository.findByName(name);
        if (role == null) {
            role = new UsersRoles();
            role.setName(name);
            role.setPrivileges(privileges);
            usersRolesRepository.save(role);
        }
        return role;
    }

}
```

## MyApplication.class for my Application

```
package com.dummy.users;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class UsersApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(UsersApplication.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UsersApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

MyController class, when I access the controller it response 404 issue

```
 @RestController
    public class UsersLinkAdminController {

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String getUsersStatus() {
            return "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                    + "<html>\n"
                    + "<head>\n"
                    + "<title>Page Title</title>\n"
                    + "<style>\n"
                    + "body {\n"
                    + "  background-color: black;\n"
                    + "  text-align: center;\n"
                    + "  color: white;\n"
                    + "  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\n"
                    + "}\n"
                    + "</style>\n"
                    + "</head>\n"
                    + "<body>\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + "<h1>Welcome to Dummy Oraganization</h1>\n"
                    + "<p>Users Module Running Sucessfully</p>\n"
                    + "<p>For More Details Call Support team</p>\n"
                    + "<img src=\"avatar.png\" alt=\"Avatar\" style=\"width:200px\">\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + "</body>\n"
                    + "</html>";
        }

    }
```

So Anyone Please tell me about the issues.

Comment: 404 in spring applications is mainly because of context not loaded because of exceptions or lack of availability of dependency. Set logger to debug mode and check logs while application startup.

Answer (score 0):

Your security configuration needs additional configuration.  You need an authenticationProvider [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270196/hybrid-authentication-spring-mvc-session-based-jwt-token-based/58272235#58272235) of inmemory:

```
 @Autowired
            public void configureInMemoryAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
            {
                auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin@123#")).roles("ADMIN");
            }
```

And DAO authenticationProvider:

```
@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());

        return authProvider;

    }
```