# Spring Security with Spring Boot: Mix Basic Authentication with JWT token authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to get Spring Security's basic authentication to work side by side with JWT token authentication with no success. I have implemented basic authentication for my web console and JWT to secure a number of API endpoints. Here's my config:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;    

@Autowired
public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

/**
 * 
 * API Security configuration
 *
 */
@Configuration
@Order(1) 
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity   
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()                
            // don't create session
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**","/refresh/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();               
        // Custom JWT based security filter
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * Form login security configuration
 *
 */
@Configuration
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ConsoleAuthenticationEntryPoint consoleAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
        http.httpBasic().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
                consoleAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
         .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/console/**").authenticated()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/*.html",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/console/home")
         .loginPage("/console/login")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
         .logout()
         .permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

}

I have noticed that the configuration I annotate with Order(1) is the one that is picked by Spring Security and the other is completely ignored. Like in the above config, I get 401 error if I try to access /console/login.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why is because neither `ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` nor `FormLoginWebSecurityConfig` uses the `antMatcher()`. This means that both security configurations will handle all paths, even though you're using `antMatchers()` afterwards. Due to this, the configuration with the lowest order (`@Order(1)`) will handle everything, while the other one will do nothing.

This is also mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity):

> The `http.antMatcher` states that this `HttpSecurity` will only be applicable to URLs that start with `/api/`

So, to fix this problem, you have to povide an `antMatcher` to one of your configurations (or both). For example, if the form login should only be applied to `/console/login` and `/console/home`, you could change the configuration to:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
    http
        .antMatcher("/console/**") // Add this
        .httpBasic().and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(consoleAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/console/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                "/*.html",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/**/*.html",
                "/**/*.css",
                "/**/*.js").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/console/home")
        .loginPage("/console/login").permitAll().and()
        .logout().permitAll().and() // Make sure to use .and() to add the .csrf()
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

Another good read about this topic is this question: [When to use Spring Security`s antMatcher()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890540/when-to-use-spring-securitys-antmatcher)

Please note that you shouldn't use the `http` builder twice like you did to add the `.csrf().disable()`, add it to the other builder like I did in the code above.

Also be aware that you'll likely have to change the order. You should put the order on the configuration with the most detailed `antMatcher()`, in this case `FormLoginWebSecurityConfig`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I used it to add basic authentication for Prometheus and continue with JWT for the rest of the site. I added an extra layer of role based security - so I replaced .authenticated() with .hasRole("MYCUSTOMROLE") and trapped in the jwtauthentication filter to not check for JWT token validation for that role. Works beautifully