# Configuring Spring Security not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am running a Spring Boot app wherein it runs a vuejs front end deployed as static resources and an API managed by Spring. I am setting up authentication and the scenario is as such.

The front end app sits at `/app` but `/` is redirected to `/app` by Spring anyway. I want a form based login for my app at '/login'. My app uses the API served by Spring and the API sits at `/api`. As such, I want the API to recognise the logged in session by the front end. But, I also want the API to be Basic authenticated. At the same time I don't want any route except `/api` to be basic authenticated, i.e. even if I am supplying an authentication header, it should still redirect me to `/login`. So,

- `/api` Basic and Session based authentication
- `/**` Only Session based authentication through a form

I am using the current code:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrls;

    @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
    private String ldapBaseDn;

    @Value("${ldap.username}")
    private String ldapSecurityPrincipal;

    @Value("${ldap.password}")
    private String ldapPrincipalPassword;

    @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
    private String ldapUserDnPattern;

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
        super();
        this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource()
                .url(ldapUrls + ldapBaseDn)
                .managerDn(ldapSecurityPrincipal)
                .managerPassword(ldapPrincipalPassword)
                .and()
                .userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern);
    }
}
```

This is not working exactly as expected. My API is authenticated via Basic and Session tokens but so is my app. i.e. I can make a GET request in Postman along with the Basic Authentication headers and the HTML to my homepage is returned.

Along with that I don't think I have a good understanding of how the configuration setup is done especially with using `and()`. It would be great if someone could direct me to some resources which explains the nitty gritties of configuration.

Comment: You have only one configuration, so all you configured are always applied. If you want two different configurations, you have to write two different configuration. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41527591/5277820.

Comment: Great! Putting this under 2 configuration blocks fixed this. But I don't really understand what's going on here? Why did I need 2 configuration blocks? Rather under what conditions would I need multiple configuration blocks?

Comment: In general you need more than one configuration, if you want to handle different requests in a different way (for example: authentication, CORS, CSRF, sessions, and a lot more). In some cases you could also handle it with one configuration, for example for CSRF you could add a ignoring path matcher.  But in your case there is no way to say, basic authentication only for some sub paths.

Comment: Ah! Good to know. If you would write an answer in this regard I would accept this as this has already solved my problem.