# Understanding requestMatchers() on spring-security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am studying some code of spring-security. I would like to understand this example that I found on internet
**1**:

```
http.requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/management/**") // (1)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests() // (2)
        .antMatchers("/management/health")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/info")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**")
        .hasRole("ACTUATOR")
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic(); (3)
```

}

I can not understand this configuration, why this code:

```
http.requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/management/**")
        .and()
```

Is before the .authorizeRequests() ? (1)

What does that mean?

Can you explanation this example?

**2:** In the second case, what is the difference?

```
http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/rest2/**")
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/rest/v1/test/hello").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/rest/v1/test/**").denyAll()
.and()
.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/rest/**")
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/rest/v1/test/hello").permitAll();
```

What is the impact using requestMatchers()?

If I send a request to "/rest/v1/test/hello2" I received a 401 Why if the rule that deny a request does not match with the antMatchers("/rest2/**") ?

Comment: Don't ask two different questions in one question. You should open two separate question, because they are unrelated.

Comment: However, the answer of your first question is that your understanding of the default is wrong. In this case default means no custom Spring Security configuration, but you have a custom Sprig Security configuration.

Comment: Your second question is very likely a duplicate. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890540/when-to-use-spring-securitys-antmatcher (it is about `antMatcher`, but the explaination is the same for `requestMatchers`.

Comment: @dur, I split my quesiton in two question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039148/understanding-default-rule-on-spring-security-httpsecurity.

I still have doubts why requestMatchers(), was used before other configurations, I almost see only authorizeRequests() in examples.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The purpose of `requestMatchers()` is to specify which requests the spring security configuration will be applied to.

For example if you have 2 endpoints `"/public"` and `"/private"` and you only want security (specifically csrf protection) applied to `"/private"`, then you could add the following configuration:

```
http
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/private/**")
        .and()
    .csrf();
```

Then, if you POST to `"/private"` you will get a 403 response.
But if you POST to `"/public"` you will get a 200, because there has been no security applied.

This is separate from `authorizeRequests` which indicates the type of **access** that is required for that endpoint, as opposed to whether security is applied at all.

In example 1 that you mention

```
http
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/management/**")
        .and() 
        ...
```

the security configuration is only applied to `"/management/**"`, so if you were to make a request to `"/foo"`, it would not be secured.

In example 2 that you mention,

```
http
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/rest2/**")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/v1/test/hello").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/rest/v1/test/**").denyAll()
        .and()
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/rest/**")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/v1/test/hello").permitAll();
```

the reason why `"/rest/v1/test/hello2"` responds with a 401 is because `"/rest/**"` is in a request matcher, so your security rule `.antMatchers("/rest/v1/test/hello").permitAll()` will apply.
If you were to make a request to `"/rest3/v1/test/hello2"`, then it would respond with a 200 because `"/rest3/**"` is not part of any request matcher.

Answer (score 15):

## **Spring Boot 3 Update**

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has been removed and Spring Security 5.5 introduced a new approach to configuring security using the `SecurityFilterChain` interface - with this the HttpSecurity builder API has been deprecated.

e.g. to allow requests on `/public/` and everything further, while keeping the ant-pattern annotation, use:

```java
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**")).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()) //other URLs are only allowed authenticated users.
        .httpBasic();
    return http.build();
  }
```

The definition of "Authenticated users" can be specified using a `JwtTokenFilter` extending a `OncePerRequestFilter` (for example).

Comment: How to add multiple URI..

Comment: You could specify multiple comma separated `AntPathRequestMatchers`

Answer (score -8):

Spring security API:
public final class HttpSecurity.RequestMatcherConfigurer
extends AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry

**Allows mapping HTTP requests that this HttpSecurity will be used for**

Comment: unclear answer. You should add an explanation