# Migrating from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to SecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring, spring-security

Here is my working security conf before migration :

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**")
                .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedPortalRoleConverter);

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationFallbackEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
    }
```

And here is my Security chain config after migration :

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain ignorePathsSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .antMatchers(
                                "/auth/**",
                                "/swagger-ui/**",
                                "/swagger-ui.html",
                                "/swagger-resources/**",
                                "/v3/api-docs/**")
                            .permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)   
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, GrantedPortalRoleConverter grantedPortalRoleConverter) throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedPortalRoleConverter);

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationFallbackEntryPoint()))
                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> configurer.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter));

        return http.build();
    }
```

With the original conf, when I call a random non existing path :

```java
    @Test
    void should_not_authenticate_or_return_not_found() throws Exception {
        logger.info("should_not_authenticate_or_return_not_found");
        
        mvc.perform(get("/toto/tata"))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());      
    }
```

I get :

```
15:44:00.230 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /toto/tata] with attributes [authenticated]
```

With the new conf, I'm just getting HTTP 404, what am I missing here please ? I can't see any difference and debug logs don't show much.

Here is the first line of log missing using the non working conf :

```
16:24:58.651 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for any request
```

But in both logs, I can see (2 lines of this for the new conf since there are 2 security chains) :

```
o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Will secure any request with (...)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation**

When you have multiple `SecurityFilterChain`s, you have to specify a request matcher, otherwise all requests will be processed by the first `SecurityFilterChain`, annotated with `@Order(1)`, and never reach the second `SecurityFilterChain`, annotated with `@Order(2)`.

In the code you shared above, this means configuring `.requestMatchers()` in `ignorePathsSecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain ignorePathsSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatchers(requests -> requests // add this block
            .antMatchers(
                "/auth/**",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/v3/api-docs/**")
        )
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .antMatchers(
                "/auth/**",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/v3/api-docs/**")
            .permitAll());

    return http.build();
}
```

This means that only the requests matching `/auth/**`, `/swagger-ui/**` etc will be processed by `ignorePathsSecurityFilterChain`, while the rest of the requests will move on to `defaultSecurityFilterChain`.

To understand the difference between `requestMatchers` and `authorizeHttpRequests` you can check out [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029258/understanding-requestmatchers-on-spring-security/57081273#57081273).

**Solution**

An even better option is to combine the `SecurityFilterChain`s into a single one. I don't see any reason why you would separate them in this case.

The resulting configuration would be:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, GrantedPortalRoleConverter grantedPortalRoleConverter) throws Exception {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedPortalRoleConverter);

    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/auth/**",
                            "/swagger-ui/**",
                            "/swagger-ui.html",
                            "/swagger-resources/**",
                            "/v3/api-docs/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationFallbackEntryPoint()))
            .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> configurer.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter));

    return http.build();
}
```

**Alternative**

Alternatively you can use a `WebSecurityCustomizer` to ignore certain endpoints:

```java
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/auth/**",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/v3/api-docs/**");
}
```

Then you would use `defaultSecurityFilterChain` as your only `SecurityFilterChain`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, indeed I ended up combining like you suggest. But I still don't get it why 2 SecurityFilterChain can't apply to the same endpoint. Maybe it's just not designed for this, but then why accept to start without warning or error ?

Comment: The filter chains are checked against in request in order. Once one matches it does not look for another one, since it would be unclear which one should apply. There are a few reasons why the request only goes through one filter chain, one of them being that there are many common filters in both chains and you would get unexpected behaviour if the filter was applied multiple times.