# Request method 'POST' is not supported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to upgrade Spring Boot from 2.7.6 to 3.0.1. I have a problem during the login action. The following is my new `WebSecurityConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig  {

    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    private final  CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService, CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler = customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/login?expired=true");
        return http.build();
    }

    // This second filter chain will secure the static resources without reading the SecurityContext from the session.
    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    SecurityFilterChain resources(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll())
            .requestCache().disable()
            .securityContext().disable()
            .sessionManagement().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Follow my `CustomUserDetailService`:

```java
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
        System.out.println(email);
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email.toLowerCase());
        System.out.println(user.getEmail());
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email.toLowerCase());
        if (user != null) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority( user.getRole()));;
            return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("username not found");
        }
    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
}
```

When I run the application I see the login page, but when I enter the credential and press submit I receive the error:

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported]

and Tomcat shows:

> HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed   Type Status Report
>
> Message Method 'POST' is not supported.

I searched for a solution but really I don't understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple `HttpSecurity` instances, you must specify a security matcher, otherwise the first `SecurityFilterChain` will process all requests, and no requests will reach the second chain.
See [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances) of the Spring Security reference documentation.

In your case the `SecurityFilterChain` called `resources` is matching all requests, because you don't have a security matcher.
Since the `resources` chain does not configure `formLogin` then Spring Security does not create the default /login POST endpoint.

You can fix this by changing `requests` to:

```
@Bean
@Order(0)
SecurityFilterChain resources(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .securityMatchers((matchers) -> matchers
            .requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**") // the requests that this SecurityFilterChain will process
        )
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyRequest().permitAll())
        .requestCache().disable()
        .securityContext().disable()
        .sessionManagement().disable();

    return http.build();
}
```

If you want more details on the difference between `authorizeHttpRequests` and `requestMatchers` you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029258/understanding-requestmatchers-on-spring-security/57081273#57081273).

Comment: Thanks, but the second chain seems to reached because I see my login page with css and js. The problem is when I try to login that I receive the method POST not supported.

Comment: The login phase should be done by the first filterChain

Comment: @EnricoMorelli Doesn't the login page appear because you have a controller mapping for GET /login?

Comment: The login page appears regularly, the problem becomes when I enter the credentials and submit its

Comment: Yes, because your code is generating the login page, but the POST /login endpoint is not being generated by Spring Security because of a misconfiguration.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work. IntelliJ gives the Cannot resolve method 'requestMatchers' in 'HttpSecurity' error

Comment: @EnricoMorelli Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited to add the updated matcher name.

Comment: Thanks, but your code doesn't work again. Now I'm unable to see the login page because  the browser shows ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score -1):

This error typically occurs when the method in the controller is not mapped to a post request. Should be something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView login(...
```

Comment: I know. But usually, the authentication should be managed by Spring Security. In the 2.7.6  Spring application, I haven't s POST method to manage login authentication.

Comment: I have been working with Spring Boot since release 1 and I have since then used the formLogin and loginPage together with a controller. I don't have experience of other configurations.

Comment: I check this article https://javatechonline.com/spring-security-userdetailsservice-using-spring-boot-3/#Step9_Write_SecurityConfig_class_Without_Using_WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to confirm that using Spring Security there isn't a POST to manage authentication