# Spring security - Request method 'POST' is not supported when using 2 authentication providers

Tags: authentication, jpa, post, spring-security

Spring Security does not let me login using one of my 2 authentication providers.

My application should be able to authenticate two types of users - `User` and `Organization` by checking information stored on the database. For that, I created two separate `WebSecurityConfiguration` classes, with different `SecurityFilterChain`, defining different form logins and using the 2 different authentication providers - which use two different `UserDetailsService` implementations (pointing to different repositories).

My endpoints for `Organization` work - both register and login, and the session is successfully created, but for `User`, my `POST` method on the login endpoint (`/auth/login/user`) is blocked - returning `Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported]` on IntelliJ as a warning, but the backend returns status `200` on Postman. The application does not crash, but the POST method is not completed - on debug, it completes as `405` and redirects the request to `/auth/login/org`.

This is `OrgWebSecurityConfiguration`'s `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
    @Bean
    @CrossOrigin
    public SecurityFilterChain orgSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .securityMatchers((matcher) -> matcher
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/*/org").anyRequest())
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/register/**")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/login/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login/org")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login/org")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/auth/org-login-success", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authenticationManager(orgAuthenticationManager(http))
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
```

`UserWebSecurityConfiguration`'s `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
    @Bean
    @CrossOrigin
    public SecurityFilterChain userSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .securityMatchers((matcher) -> matcher
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/*/user").anyRequest())
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/register/**")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/login/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login/user")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login/user")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/auth/login-success", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authenticationManager(userAuthenticationManager(http))
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
```

`userAuthProvider`:

```
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider userAuthProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider userAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        userAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        userAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return userAuthenticationProvider;
    }
```

`orgAuthProvider`:

```
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider orgAuthProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider orgAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        orgAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(organizationDetailsService);
        orgAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return orgAuthenticationProvider;
    }
```

Both `orgAuthenticationManager` and `userAuthenticationManager` were created by defining an authentication provider of type `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and setting the proper `UserDetailsService` for each, implementing the created auth providers on `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. In this case, `User`'s authentication manager is set to be the primary one, by using `@Primary` annotation.

I've tried using `@Order(0)` annotation on `UserWebSecurityConfiguration` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74938797/request-method-post-is-not-supported), but the problem persisted. I also disabled csrf.

Comment: [You should be using `securityMatchers`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances) to specify the URLs that the `SecurityFilterChain` should be invoked. It is always important to share the whole configuration even if they look the same, that help us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I edited the question and included both `SecurityFilterChain`s, along with the authentication providers.

Comment: may i ask why you havnt enabled spring DEBUG or TRACE logging and read your logs to see what the problem actually is, before asking here?

Comment: I have enabled debug, but I still don't get where the problem is. It says the same thing as the question title, and gives status 405. After that, the request is mapped to `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)` - which I assume it would be `/login?error` - and gets redirected as a `GET` method to `/auth/login/org`. Note that my `POST` method was sent to `/auth/login/user`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by combining the two SecurityFilterChains into one, and adding both `AuthenticationProvider`s to `userAuthenticationManager`, like so:

```java
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AuthenticationManager userAuthenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .authenticationProvider(userAuthProvider())
                .authenticationProvider(orgAuthProvider())
                .build();
    }
```

And then normally adding `userAuthenticationManager` to `securityFilterChain` (previous `userSecurityFilterChain`):

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .securityMatchers((matcher) -> matcher
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/*").anyRequest())
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/register/**")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/login")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/auth/login-success", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authenticationManager(userAuthenticationManager(http)) // AuthenticationManager with 2 auth providers is added here
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
```

Now, I only use one form login to authenticate both `User` and `Organization` - `/auth/login`.

EXPLANATION:

By adding `trace=true` on `application.properties`, I was able to identify that a `POST` request to `/auth/login/user` returned status `405` and was redirected as a `GET` request to `/auth/login/org`. That meant that `orgSecurityFilterChain` was being considered the "default" filter on the application, even though `userSecurityFilterChain` was marked with `Order(0)`. It gave permission to access `/auth/*/user`, but what was happening was that probably even though I accessed user endpoints - which should use `userSecurityFilterChain` - `orgSecurityFilterChain` was still used, since it was the default filter - which mapped `/auth/login/org` as its form login. That means that even though the request was supposed to be handled by `userSecurityFilterChain` - which mapped the login endpoint as `/auth/login/user` - it was being handled by `orgSecurityFilterChain`, which did not support `POST` requests to `/auth/login/user`.

Comment: Please note that your `userAuthenticationManager` method is incorrectly accessing the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. You should instead directly instantiate a `ProviderManager` with your list of `AuthenticationProvider`s. Additionally, I believe the `authenticationManager` DSL call is unnecessary because you are publishing `AuthenticationManager` as a `@Bean` which is auto-wired into Spring Security's filter chain(s).

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Thanks for the advice. If I may ask, can you explain why `userAuthenticationManager` access to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is incorrect in this case? I didn't understand why. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)` is intended to access the "local" authentication manager builder internally when building a specific filter chain. It would be quite complicated to explain in a comment and involves a lot of internal framework complexity, but the short version is that publishing an `@Bean` should not rely on hacks that reach for internal framework implementation details, when it is much easier and correct to simply `return new ProviderManager(provider1, provider2, ...)`.