# Spring Boot serving static content blocked by security

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I started Spring Boot + Angular application and for now I want to deploy whole thing as a jar. So I created maven config, where angular app gets built and then is copied to /target/classes/resources

But every request to root (localhost:8080) gets blocked by security. When I disable it i can see the page, which means the whole thing is deployed correctly, but somehow spring does not allow me to see it. Here is my simple security config, I want static resources to be unprotected, while any other request requires authentication:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
A minimal example of my problem is here: 
https://gitlab.com/jnowacki/security-issue-demo

EDIT 2:
I tries all the things from this post:
[Serving static web resources in Spring Boot & Spring Security application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916894/serving-static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-application)
Do I do something wrong on a conceptual level? Is it wrong to serve static content along with Spring Boot app?

Comment: @dur i added a link to repo with minimal example. I need to serve index without any auth, and any other request after authentication. I know i can permit all and then secure just some path after e.g. /api but that is not the point.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want do permitAll the URL `/` then you have to add that URL to your configuration.

Comment: @dur when i configure it as follows:
        `http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();`
index.html is allowed, but request for css asks for credentials.

Answer (score 4):

Add this additional override:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST);
}
```

where `AUTH_WHITELIST` will contain the paths to be ignored. For instance:

```
private static final String[] SWAGGER_AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        // -- swagger ui
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/resources/**"
};
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? There is no mention of similar thing in the release notes of 2.1: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes

Comment: i added link to minimal example, i dont think its specific to 2.1, its just i have this version and it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 1):

try below.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
    .ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
```

Refer [spring-securitys-antmatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890540/when-to-use-spring-securitys-antmatcher)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to allow static resources to be ignored by spring security

```
//this method allows static resources to be neglected by spring security
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `StaticResourceLocation` [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/StaticResourceLocation.html):

```
.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
```

will permit access to CSS, JS, ICO, images and **NOT to html**.

To permit `index.html` you can use following configuration:

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
```

Answer (score 0):

// extends WebSecrityConfiguratesAdapeter

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Overide
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception { 
         web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, ALL_ESCAPE)
            .antMatchers("*.js")
            .antMatchers(")
            .antMatchers(BOWER_COMPONENTS)
            .antMatchers(I18N)
            .antMatchers(CONTENT);           
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must match real path, or example:

```
.pathMatchers("/assets/**", "/static/**")
            .permitAll()ere
```