# using HttpSecurity.requestMatchers in class ResourceServerConfiguration.configure in spring oauth2

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have been struggling to understand how and when to use `HttpSecurity.requestMatchers`. Though I use `HttpSecurity.requestMatchers` but I have call `authorizeRequests` and `antMatchers` to specify the security rules.

When should I use

```
 http.requestMatchers()
              .antMatchers("/secure/**","/patients/**","/patient/**", "/hello/**")
              .and()
              .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secure/**","/books/**","/book/**", "/hello/**")
              .hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER");
```

over

```
      http
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secure/**","/books/**","/hello/**", "/hello/**")
      .hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER");
```

A scenario would help me to understand the use-case of `HttpSecurity.requestMatchers`

I did look into [requestMatchers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#requestMatchers--), but still not clear to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890540/when-to-use-spring-securitys-antmatcher

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to configure multiple `HttpSecurity` in your application, than you would typically use `HttpSecurity.requestMatchers()` or one of the alternative (but similar) configuration options:

- `HttpSecurity.requestMatcher(RequestMatcher)`
- `HttpSecurity.antMatcher(String)`
- `HttpSecurity.mvcMatcher(String)`
- `HttpSecurity.regexMatcher(String)`

See the reference in [6.10 Multiple HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity)

For example, if your application has a set of API's rooted at the base path `/api` and another category of endpoints for the admin section of the application rooted at the base path `/admin`, than you might define 2x `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` for your application as such:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**")
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/endpoint1")
                        .hasRole("USER1");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class AdminWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/endpoint1")
                        .hasRole("ADMIN1");

        }
    }
}
```

However, if you only provide 1x `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` than you don't need to configure `HttpSecurity.requestMatchers()` (or any of the alternatives) because it will automatically default to `HttpSecurity.requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)`. So for these configuration cases, this is sufficient:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(...
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this makes sense?

Comment: So, you mean when I make call to `requestMathers` and then `antMatchers` , it does tell that this http security configuration (or **filter chain**) responsible to handle the the patterns( for example`api/endpoint1`).. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Using `http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**")` matches on a specific `SecurityFilterChain` (which is built from a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter `)