# How to apply URL and role based authentication in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to apply URl and role based authentication in the following way

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/restApi/**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .permitAll();
```

But after entering username and password, I am getting back default login screen provided by Spring Boot.

If I use `permitAll()` instead of `hasRole()`, then it works correctly.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: What's the point of `permitAll()` at the end?

Comment: What URL do you call?

Comment: Where do you apply the roles to your users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dur answers a good way to use multiple rest endpoints here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41527591/2566098

I tested this example with a fresh project and had to add "{noop}" in front of the password string to get it to work but it works great.

Basically we separate each endpoint into its own extension of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

In this example it is:

```
http
    .antMatcher("/api/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
    .and().httpBasic();
```

While you have it reversed and use antmatchers plural and are missing anyRequest()
(not sure if this makes a difference):

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/rest/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```